# Apache configuration to get Laravel API in this url : www.example.com/api

Tags: angularjs, apache, laravel-5.4

I'm not sure this is working or not, I tried but it had no effect. So no errors but something still seems to be wrong.

What I want is that my api (Laravel 5.4) get this root url : www.example.com/api

Here is what fits my idea :

```
<VirtualHost \*:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/angular-client
</VirtualHost>      

<VirtualHost>     
  ServerName example.com/api
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/api/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

Best regards,

Joseph Gremaud

EDIT : 
Just found out it's easier to use Directory with an alias like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot    /var/www/spmo
        ServerName      spmo.corp.sftcm.ch
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
<Directory /var/www/spmo>
        Require all granted
        DirectoryIndex  index.html
        Options +Indexes
</Directory>
Alias /api /var/www/api/public
<Directory /var/www/api/public>
        Require all granted
        Options +Indexes
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now only one problem remains in Laravel configuration because all my routes are redirecting like this :

Expected : spmo.corp.sftcm.ch/api/api/v1/teams -> should give me JSON response.
Result : spmo.corp.sftcm.ch/api/api/v1/teams -> gave me a 404 error.

I know that this not good to have api/api but i'll change laravel prefixes when I solve my issue.

Comment: Was this problem Solved? I Kinda have the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the IP of the virtual host argument on the VirtualHost directive:

```
<VirtualHost \*:80>     
  ServerName example.com/api
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/api/public
</VirtualHost>
```

You can use `journalctl | tail` on console to see those type of errors.

Comment: As I have only 1 IP on this server, I don't need use an IP as *:80 refers automatically to server own IP which is intented.
As I'm new to apache configuration I don't know if it's strongly recommended or not in my case